# redirect to http back after https in tomcat + jsf

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf

I have a login page that I would like to show in https. After validating the user, I would like to transfer him back to http.

So I declared in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Login and Restricted Space URLs</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/general/enter.jsf</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>  
  <user-data-constraint>
   <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>

 <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Rest of the Application</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/general/home.jsf</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
   <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

and I see that the login page is in https.

But in my action:

```
public String doLogin() throws Exception {
  ...
  User user = service.getUserByNameAndCompany(name, company);
  ......
                return "/general/home.jsf";
 }
```

The bean redirects the user to

> https ://mycomputer:8443/MYProject/general/home.jsf

and I would like it to be back

> http: //mycomputer:8080/MYProject/general/home.jsf

How can I do it?

Comment: While this approach protects the password, it exposes the sessionid cookie. So an attacker who can sniff the traffic can act as the victim.

Comment: So what do you suggest to do in order to protect the sessionid cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF navigation will redirect you to a page within the same application (that means you can navigate only inside `https: //mycomputer:8080/MYProject` ).

What you can do is to navigate to a page like `/general/redirect.jsf` and from there use a header or javascript redirection to the url you want.

Comment: but the header or javascript probably need the full URL like:
http: //mycomputer:8080/MYProject/general/home.jsf
and I wouldn't want to put the full URL since the computer name/port/project may change. I would like it to be relevant to the application..

Comment: Use a configuration file or so or change 8080/8443 to 80/443 so that you don't need to use port numbers, but just replace "https" by "http" in URL. Use `ExternalContext#redirect()` to redirect programmatically and then `return null` (or just declare method `void`).

Comment: You can read the URL from the request and then parse and remove the "s" in the URL: You can do this in Javascript o programmatically in your backing bean as BalusC suggests.